# HTML coding style: attribute starts on a new line

Tags: html, html5

sublvl's front end developer seems to have a strange coding style that I've never seen before. Every time they begin a new element, immediately after the element name they insert a line break. The first thing that appears on the next line is the first attribute of the element. For example:

```
id="player-container"><div
id="player-bar"><div
id="player-controls-wrapper"><div
id="player-controls"><div
id ="player-controls-buttons"> <a
```

The above code was found [here](http://www.sublvl.com/stream/).

I've never seen this kind of coding style before. What's going on here? Is this just a quirky style or is there some reasoning behind it?

Comment: [Voting to close.] Who cares? Whitespace is irrelevant. Note, though, that code was minified.

Comment: @Su' Well, clearly I care since I posted the question. It's an idiosyncratic coding style that might have some non-obvious reason or benefit.

Comment: It's not a coding style, at least in terms of a person doing it. It's minification. I can't imagine a single benefit of this output to a human. The rule isn't even as simple as you describe: elements that *don't* have attributes aren't broken across lines, suggesting it's a simple form of whitespace removal(and why only the first attribute?). Script tags are also left alone, as they're more vulnerable to breakage. There's likely other exceptions. As far as people, that's just confusing. Scanning for opening tags at the *end* of lines is ridiculous from a human perspective. (And so on.)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be minification by the [W3 Total Cache WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/). This strategy of inserting a line break at the end of the element name seems to be to prevent the line length from becoming too excessive, while taking advantage of the fact that a line break is valid white space for separating tokens in HTML.